# How to add multiple resolvers in a type (Apollo-server)

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I have used `express-graphql` and there i used to do something like this.

```
const SubCategoryType = new ObjectType({
  name: 'SubCategory',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: IDType },
    name: { type: StringType },
    category: {
      type: CategoryType,
      resolve: parentValue => getCategoryBySubCategory(parentValue.id)
    },
    products: {
      type: List(ProductType),
      resolve: parentValue => getProductsBySubCategory(parentValue.id)
    }
  })
});
```

Here I have multiple resolvers, `id and name` are fetched directly from the result. and the category and products have there own database operation. and so on. 
Now I am working on `apollo-server` and I can't find a way to replicate this.

for example I have a type

```
   type Test {
    something: String
    yo: String
    comment: Comment
  }
   type Comment {
    text: String
    createdAt: String
    author: User
  }
```

and in my resolver I want to split it up, for example something like this

```
text: {
    something: 'value',
    yo: 'value',
    comment: getComments();
}
```

NOTE: this is just a representation of what I need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add type-specific resolvers to handle specific fields. Let's say you have the following schema (based on your example):

```
type Query {
  getTest: Test
}
type Test {
  id: Int!
  something: String
  yo: String
  comment: Comment
}
type Comment {
  id: Int!
  text: String
  createdAt: String
  author: User
}
type User {
  id: Int!
  name: String
  email: String
}
```

Let's also assume you have the following DB methods:

- `getTest()` returns an object with fields `something`, `yo` and
  `commentId`
- `getComment(id)` returns an object with fields `id`, `text`, `createdAt` and `userId`
- `getUser(id)` returns an object with fields `id`, `name` and `email`

Your resolver will be something like the following:

```js
const resolver = {
  // root Query resolver
  Query: {
    getTest: (root, args, ctx, info) => getTest()
  },
  // Test resolver
  Test: {
    // resolves field 'comment' on Test
    // the 'parent' arg contains the result from the parent resolver (here, getTest on root)
    comment: (parent, args, ctx, info) => getComment(parent.commentId)
  },
  // Comment resolver
  Comment: {
    // resolves field 'author' on Comment
    // the 'parent' arg contains the result from the parent resolver (here, comment on Test)
    author: (parent, args, ctx, info) => getUser(parent.userId)
  },
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Let me try this and get back to you

Comment: It worked. :) Couldn't find it in docs though, do you have any docs link which explains this well? and like this, won't my resolvers be hard to manage? 
It would be helpful if you share some tips. As I am using apollo-server for first time.

Comment: @Sarmad You can find the basic documentation about apollo-server resolvers [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/resolvers.html). Think of resolvers as "bubbling up" from your root Query or Mutation: if a field is not directly resolved in the parent resolver, then it must be resolved by a child resolver. You can also use child resolvers to override the value of a given field under certain conditions (for instance, you might want to *null* a field when a user is not authenticated). If you have any specific questions, I'll be happy to help if I can. :)

Comment: As your resolvers get more complex, I encourage you to put any type-specific resolver in its own file, and then aggregate all your resolvers in a `resolvers.js` file. You'll find your code much easier to maintain that way. Let me know if you want me to add an example of such a directory structure in my answer.